# Javascript form validation error like facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a login page like facebook. Used html and javascript I managed to create login page with predefined username and password.If you type correct password then it will redirect to a new page. But if you type wrong password or username then it will show error message on the side of textbox like real facebook

my code is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Fakebook -Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="login">
<div id="facebook-Bar">
  <div id="facebook-Frame">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="">Facebook</a> </div>


       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>

<div class="loginbox radius">
<h2 style="color:#141823; text-align:center;">Log in to Facebook</h2>
    <div class="loginboxinner radius">
        <div class="loginheader">
        </div>

        <div class="loginform">

            <form id="login" action="" method="post">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Email" value="" class="radius" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="radius" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="radius title" onclick="check(this.form)" name="client_login">Log In</button>
                </p>
  <script language="javascript">
    function check(form)
     {
      if(form.username.value == "rohit" && form.password.value == "password")
       {
        window.open('target.html')
       }
     else
      {
       document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "wrong username"
      }
     }
   </script>

        <br>
        <br>
    <a href="" style="color:#0000FF; text-decoration:none">forgot your password?</a></label></td>
<a href="" style="color:#0000FF; text-decoration:none">| sign up for facebook</a></label></td>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the facebook error message

[image: Here is the facebook error message]

Comment: Just for the record... NEVER use javascript authentication in real life situations. For education and practice purposes, it is ok, but do not use it for the real thing, because anyone would be able to see the code (so they'd see the username and the password).

Comment: Yes I know that bro. I am only making this for a educational purpose.